# Wicket: passing parameter to wicket:link

Tags: java, wicket

My page contains:

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="link">This link</a> has been clicked 
<span wicket:id="count"></span> times.

<wicket:link>
    <a href="newPage.html?foo=[value]">new page</a>
</wicket:link>
```

How can I pass the 'count' value into **wicket:link** instead of '[value]'?

Comment: Dummy suggestion (will probably not work): Use <wicket:container/> as [value] and assign it to the same model as the count-span. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726572/how-to-put-a-parameter-on-a-wicket-link-in-html Still the best way to go is to use a normal link and define foo = count in PageParameters

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach. First of all, wicket:link isn't meant for dynamic linking, secondly, you shouldn't round-trip things already known on server side as query parameters, and thirdly, use models. Models are the alpha and omega of everything in Wicket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @biziclop - do not use  for this case.

Possible options:
 1. If "link" is an AjaxLink then make the second link a BookmarkablePageLink and update it too with the new value as a page parameter

2. Make the second link a Link that uses `setResponsePage(NewPage.class, pageParametersWithValue)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to respond to the link-action (onClick) at server-side, the following code should be enough:

```
add(new WebMarkupContainer("linkToNewPage")).add(AttributeModifier.replace("href", "newPage.html?foo=" + count));
```

(as it was already stated, consider using a replacement model for the attribute modifier rather than accessing the count variable at construction time)